# React.createRef() causing error 'expected ref to be function or string'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I upgraded my React to 16.3.2 and used `React.createRef()` as seen here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref

But when I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Expected ref to be a function or a string.
```

When I look at what the function React.createRef() actually returns, I see this:

```
{ current: null }
```

What is going wrong here? Has the implementation changed?

I am using react-router-dom for routing, and my component is a `class` component.

EDIT: this is my code:

```
export class MyComponent extends Component { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.cardRef = React.createRef();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                ...
                <Card ref={this.cardRef}>
                    ...
                </Card>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your code? It's hard to debug what's going on without actually seeing what's going on

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html there seems to be some good detail about `ref` in here, but without more context I can't help you beyond that

Comment: Just to check, did you also update React-DOM?

Comment: @Hamms I've added the code

Comment: @markerikson yes, I upgraded both react and react-dom to 16.3.2

Comment: @SterlingArcher I've added my code for context

Comment: What is the Card component?

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us best help you. The code you shared doesn't generate the error, so it doesn't give us any insight into why you might be getting one

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk it's just a custom component that renders a div with a bunch of styling

Comment: @aditi is it a functional component?

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk no. I just tried it with a simple div 
`<div ref={this.loginErrorCardRef} > test card </div>` and it did not work.

Comment: @aditi can you confirm that you are actually using React 16.3.2? What do you see if you log `React.version`?

Comment: @Hamms yes. When I log `React.version` I get: `16.3.2`

Comment: This sounds strange. Have you tried removing `node_modules` and doing a fresh install?

Comment: Are you using some alternative to react-dom like react-tv?

Comment: I am getting the same error/warning. I'm using react 16.6.3 with react native.

Answer (score 7):

To address this:

> What is going wrong here? Has the implementation changed?

Nope. It just returns an Object with a property `current` being set to null. No [magic here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactCreateRef.js). You just initiate property in a component with such object and then you pass a reference of this object to the component. React then at some point reassigns `current`.

```
this.component = React.createRef() // this.component = { current: null }
// we pass a reference to object above and react will mutate current property at some point
<div ref={this.component} />
```

The error message seems to suggest you are still using an older version of react. What I would suggest is to

- make sure you got the latest versions of both `react` and `react-dom` (16.3.2) declared in package.json
- then removed node_modules and install it again

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've added an edit with my code - as you can see there, I'm creating the object in my `constructor` and assigning it to a component in my `render()` function... but I am still getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with my `defaultProps`.  Since we cannot use `useRef hook` in `defaultProps`; this is what worked for me:

```js
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  formRef: React.createRef()
}
```

Good Luck...